# CSS inline vs encoded in data URI?

Tags: css, data-uri

I was looking at the implementation of someone's website this morning and saw they were defining CSS via a data-uri in a LINK tag.

I understand the rational for putting, say, images into a data-uri and *including those in CSS*, but I'm unclear why someone would choose to include CSS that way when you could just as easily do it inline.

I did see they had an ID in the link. Could it be they are dynamically grabbing this CSS from the DOM then using it for the value of a "style" of a dynamically generated element? I'm not a front-end jock but I believe there are other ways to do this.

Here is the HTML:

```
<link id="noteanywherecss" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="data:text/css,.note-anywhere%20.closebutton%7Bbackground-image%3A%20url%28chrome-extension%3A//bohahkiiknkelflnjjlipnaeapefmjbh/asset/deleteButton.png%29%3B%7D%0A.note-anywhere%20%7Bbackground-color%3A%20%23FFF046%3B%7D%0A.note-anywhere%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%23000066%3B%7D%0A.note-anywhere%20%20.edit%20%7Bfont-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20sans-serif%3B%7D%0A.note-anywhere%20%20.edit%20%7Bfont-size%3A%2014px%3B%7D%0A.note-anywhere%20.timestamp%20%7Bbackground-color%3A%20%23DDBB00%3B%7D%0A.note-anywhere%20.timestamp%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%23FFFFFF%3B%7D">
```

Comment: That's weird indeed. Maybe they're trying to target only browsers that support data-uris?

Comment: +1 good question. I suppose you do not mean inline style but author header css declarations vs. "external" style declarations with data uri. Inline styles are these declared directly at the tags and have higher specificity.

Comment: @FabianBarney To clarify "inline style": I meant using a <style> element in the <head>, not the style attribute.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be coming from the NoteAnywhere chrome plugin rather than whatever site you were on. There was a bug in the chrome developer API which mangled url() properties referencing the plug in (the `chrome-extension://` part) when inserted as CSS with `chrome.tabs.insertCSS`. it was resolved a year ago, so you probably won't see this workaround used much anymore.

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! I had forgotten I had that plugin installed. I'm going to assume that, aside from this sort of workaround, there is no other justification for using this construct?